MobSF reports insecure Random Number Generator in Android project, but I haven't used it—how to resolve?
I ran a MobSF scan on my Android project and encountered a warning about the use of an insecure Random Number Generator (java.util.Random). However, I haven't explicitly used Random anywhere in my code.
